How sp3 hybridized lone pair is forming double bond in Hyperconjugation?
I have the following alkene which performs Hyperconjugation, the 'alpha H' is removed from the 'alpha C' which is 'sp3' hybridized, but when it performs resonance and forms the double bond with the adjacent carbon the hybridization must change from 'sp3' to 'sp2' for the lone pair to reside in 'p' orbital which will make the double bond.
But according to my teacher, when we look at benzene and remove a H+, the lone pair doesn't participate in resonance as it is 'sp2' hybridized and only 'p' orbitals will perform in resonance.
My question is that in both the scenarios lone pair does not initially reside in the 'p' orbital but in one it will switch it's hybridization to perform resonance but not in the other, why?

These structures where you remove a proton to show hyperconjugation create much confusion. Nothing is removed, it’s σ orbitals delocalizing their electrons into vacant p or π* orbitals, resulting in a net lower energy bonding interactions. In benzene, that lone pair lies orthogonal to the aromatic system, and cannot ‘switch’ because that carbon already has a p-orbital taking part in the system. You cannot have 2 different p-orbitals in the same orientation; consequently, you cannot have it interact. Even if it could, it would lead to antibonding (higher energy) interaction.
